# Registering resources and packages in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I decided to replace **Web**.XML in this part:

```
   <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-
     class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-     
     class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
```

I point to the servlet container **Jersey**, which will accept requests to 
**REST**-Controllers, indicating that at boot it is necessary to scan the package **REST** on the path **com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest**, and indicate that the base URI for all Methods and classes of the resource, is filled with **/api/***

Starting with the **JAX-RS 2.x** version, you can use the **Application** or 
**ResourceConfig** classes to register packages and resources.

I executed the code like this:

```
  @ApplicationPath("api")
    public class JerseyConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest");
        register(EmployeApi.class);
    }
    }
```

Thus it would be necessary to specify, which package and in it under packages should be scanned.  Using the annotation **@ApplicationPath("api")**, I thought to replace

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

But nothing works.

What can be a mistake?
And why do I need to specify resource classes, because I have specified a package for scanning?

Why does this method not replace Web.XML and how to replace Web. xml?

And if the resource classes can be many, they will need to be in large quantities
Register?
That is, the use of Web.XML is better?

Or can it be circumvented?

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.rest.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.rest.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>     
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlets.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Do you have the jersey-container-servlet dependency?

Comment: does that mean ?                                                                                                                 <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>

Comment: No... without the 'core'. You can remove the one with the 'core'. The one without it will pull it in. But you need the one without 'core' to make the Java only config work.

Answer (score 0):

So, how told **Paul Samsotha** (above in the comment), need to change artefact
**jersey-container-servlet-core** on **artefact jersey-container-servlet**.

This is pom.xml now.

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>${mysql.version}</version>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.27</version>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.rest.version}</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>       
   </dependency>

       <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>${servlets.version}</version>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <resource-ref>
        <description>This section describes link to the DataSource JNDI resource</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/personnel_department_db_link</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

And the config file, that register classes and package

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JerseyConfig  extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        packages("com.skillsimprover.restexamples.rest");
        register(AuthenticationResource.class);
        register(AccessDeniedExceptionMapper.class);
        register(AuthenticationExceptionMapper.class);
        register(DataNotFoundExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

I have a question.

I've seen examples where resource classes are registered, and unless the **JerseyСonfig** package is unregistered, it's not enough for Jersey to find the resource class.
Is it necessary to register **ExceptionMapper** type classes in **JerseyСonfig** if they are located in a package that is already registered for scanning?

Comment: The scanning is recursive. If the `com.skillsimprover.restexamples` is the base package, and you put that, it will scan all sub-packages also, recursively. Also you can pass multiple packages to the `packages()` method. In order for the mappers to be discovered in the scanning, they need to be annotated with `@Provider`. You don't need to manually register them.